# Facebook - Invalid Scopes: manage_pages , publish_pages when my app in live mode

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login, laravel-socialite

I am using Laravel version 5.8 and I am using Laravel Sociallite plugin to connect users with Facebook.

Now I want to get `pulbish_pages` and `manage_pages` access so that I can post on my Facebook page.

I have tried following code:

```
public function redirectToProvider() {
    return Socialite::with('facebook')->scopes(['manage_pages','publish_pages'])->redirect();
}
```

Now when I click on login with the Facebook button it shows error like:

> Invalid Scopes: manage_pages,publish_pages. This message is only
> shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions
> if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at:
> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

[image]

Comment: Before you get your app’s usage of these permissions approved in review, they will only work for people with a role in the app, and only while the app is still in dev mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/

You have to get those permissions approved by Facebook before you can go live with your App. Without approval, they will only work for users with a role in the App.

Comment: Sure , I try for permissions approval.